# Visual Studio 2010 win32 compiled application does not work on windows xp

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi, windows-xp

I'm working on a project that should run on all windows platforms. It is written in c++, using only the Windows API. When I compile it in Visual Studio 6 on Windows XP, I can run it on Windows XP. When I run it in Visual Studio 2010 and run it on Windows XP it did not work. I did install *vcredist2010_x86*, *vcredist2010sp1_x86* and .NET versions 3.5 and 4.0 on Windows XP SP3. But it still doesn't work. I added the following preprocessor symbols to my project:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#define WINVER 0x0501
#define NTDDI_VERSION 0x0501
```

but it still doesn't work. My VS 2010 platform toolset is *v100*.

**Question**: What do I need to do to compile an application using Visual Studio 2010, that can be executed on Windows XP?

Comment: you got any compilation warning or errors ? what happen exactly when you try to run the program ?

Comment: What toolset platform you've got set?

Comment: "but it still doesn't work" - care to clarify that? You appear to have followed [Using the Windows Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745(v=vs.85).aspx), but we honeslty don't know for sure, as those must be properly set going in to *any* compilation source. For all we know the `#define` list you present is being done *after* your PCH inclusion, which would be wrong. And the redist you installed came from the `redist` folder of **your** build machine, right? (it is updated when you patch VS).

Comment: @ProXicT "My VS 2010 platform toolset is v100." - would seem pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: @WhozCraig Oh, I missed that, sorry. When I was writing one app targeting windows XP, I had to set the platform toolset to Windows XP (v100_xp).

Comment: @ProXicT I may be wrong, but I believe that compatibility toolchain was added in vs2012. I know the one you to which you're referring.

Comment: @ProXicT: That's not correct. Visual Studio 2010 supports building for Windows XP out-of-the-box. You are probably referring to a later version of the IDE, and the toolset you used was v120_xp (not v100_xp).

Comment: @IInspectable It has been some time ago, I don't really remember. But after doing some research, you're right, it was on VS2012.

Comment: On which platform is VS2010 used to build the executable?  Is it build as 32 or 64 bit, debug or release.

Comment: @cup: The platform used to build a binary is of no significance, whatsoever.

Comment: The NTDDI_VERSION be 0x05010300.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745(v=vs.85).aspx#visual_c___and_the_windows_header_files

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VS2010_sp1 on window_7_sp1_x64 and with 'release' mode. 
I added #define previous to my include section.
And I've tested NTDDI_VERSION to 0x05010300 but problem is still alived! The error, showed by win_xp is:
"program.exe has encountered a ploblem and needs to close."
At all, I think, program needs dll or something to install on windows xp to run correctly!